# UICollectionView locks main thread for ~10 seconds on performBatchUpdates

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview, nsfetchedresultscontroller, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a collectionview with 300 cells, driven by an NSFetchedResultsController. Every so often, all of the objects update, so I receive delegate messages telling me so, and I let the collection view handle the updates as I would a tableview. Unfortunately it locks the main thread for a few seconds every time this happens... I'm not sure why. Here's my code:

```
-(void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{

    [self.cascadeViewController.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{

    NSLog(@"performingBatchUpdates");

    for (NSDictionary *change in self.changes) {

        [change enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSNumber *key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {

            NSFetchedResultsChangeType type = [key unsignedIntegerValue];

            if (type == NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert) {

                [self.cascadeViewController.collectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:@[obj]];

            } else if (type == NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete) {

                [self.cascadeViewController.collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:@[obj]];

            } else if (type == NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate) {

                [self.cascadeViewController.collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:@[obj]];

            } else if (type == NSFetchedResultsChangeMove) {

                [self.cascadeViewController.collectionView moveItemAtIndexPath:obj[0] toIndexPath:obj[1]];

            }

        }];
    }

    NSLog(@"performingBatchUpdates end");

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    NSLog(@"completion");

    // TODO: implement
    //    [self configureMessageAndFooterView];

}];

NSLog(@"end of method");

[self.changes removeAllObjects];

}
```

What's going on here? All 300 objects updating at once is not going to happen constantly in my app's real-life execution but enough that I need to worry about it. I'm using a stock UICollectionViewFlowLayout - do I need to do something more custom?

Comment: You should profile it.

Comment: I have - it's doing a lot of stuff on internal API calls. It hits [UICollectionViewUpdate _computeGaps] and seems to do a lot of sorting of NSArrays and indexPath comparisons. Doesn't seem to be calling anything that's a delegate method I could modify, or a UICollectionViewFlowLayout method I could replace.

Comment: did you solve the problem in the meantime? i hit the same problem with 600 items in my collectionview locking the main thread for 20 seconds!

Answer (score 5):

Had the same issue with `performBatchUpdates:completion:` locking the main thread for seconds in a collection view of just ~100 elements.

After spending way too much time on the issue I found a solution: **ensure the cell's size (as returned in `-collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:` or defined via the `itemSize` property of your layout) has not a fractional value**. I solved my performance issues by applying `floor` on the computed height of my cells.

That being said, I have no idea *why* this happens. By looking at the stack trace of our profiled runs, a lot of time is spent in `-[UIViewCollectionViewUpdate _computeGaps]`, which in turns invokes `-[NSArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:]` hundreds or even thousands of times (as well as `CFSortIndexes`, `__CFSimpleMergeSort`…). By just using an integer value for the height of our cells, `sortedArrayUsingSelector` is invoked less than 10 times and the whole process completes in a fraction of a second.

Answer (score 0):

I vaguely recall seeing behavior like this before, but I don't have a solution for the `NSFetchedResultsController` + `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` combo because we stopped using both of those classes due to a multitude of issues. You might consider checking out the alternatives we open sourced:

1. [TLIndexPathTools](https://github.com/wtmoose/TLIndexPathTools) as a replacement for `NSFetchedResultsController`. It provides a `TLIndexPathController` class that is very similar to `NSFetchedResultsController` except it also works with plain arrays and it can do animated sorting an filtering (unlike `NSFetchedResultsController`. There are numerous sample projects, including a [Core Data](https://github.com/wtmoose/TLIndexPathTools/blob/master/Examples/Core%20Data/Core%20Data/CoreDataCollectionViewController.m) one.
2. [VCollectionViewGridLayout](https://github.com/vast-eng/uicollectionview-gridlayout) as a replacement for `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`. It is a uniform, vertical scrolling grid, so it isn't as flexible as `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`, but   the animations are generally much better in most cases it does sticky headers (like `UITableView` headers). There are a couple of sample projects that let you toggle between `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and `VCollectionViewGridLayout` to see the improvement.

We have an iPad app with a grid-like collection view containing around 1000 items and the above gives us great performance and nice smooth animation as our Core Data database updates in the background.